# How can I tell what a rectangle intersects with?

Tags: xna, 2d, collision-detection

I understand XNA's `Rectangle` class is rather limited, but surely there is a way to tell what a `Rectangle` is intersecting with?

If I had `Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle(stuff here);` how would I retrieve what is currently (if there is anything) intersecting `boundingBox`? Is there any easy method to detect if *anything* is intersecting it instead of testing with two individual rectangles with `boundingBox.intersects()`? Similarly, if this is possible, how would I retrieve what rectangle it is colliding with?

If there isn't any easy way of doing it, how would you go about implementing this if you had loads of possible rectangles you want to hit-test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this. What you're looking for is a container, that holds references to rectangles that are insides its bounds. This isn't an easy thing to do when you really think about it.

There is no way for the rectangle object to know any other rectangle object exists, let alone know if one is inside of it or not. However, there is a few data structures that do what you want.

For 2D, which I'm assuming you're working in, there's a structure called a Quadtree. A Quadtree can start as a single container spanning the entire map. Now, as you add collidable objects to your game, you must ( manually ) add those objects to the quadtree. The quadtree can then split up into smaller areas recursively depending on the number of objects in the game. The result is that you can pass the quadtree a rectangle, and it can quite quickly return to you all the rectangles that lie in that area.

However, moving objects around the quadtree is a whole other story. Here's a better explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Of course, I wouldn't recommend over complicating things. Unless you're building a fairly complex game, there's nothing wrong with checking every rectangle with each other.

Comment: Ah dang it! Thanks for the reply, I'll look into "quadtrees" but I think I will probably take my chances with checking each rectangle. For a gaming library, the rectangle class is surprisingly limited, it's really annoying!

Comment: Yeah, that's the smartest idea now. I know what you're looking for seems simple, but it's actually much harder to pull off. If the rectangle class were to do this, it would have to be very closely managed. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe the rectangle class even comes from the xna library( probably why it only takes ints ).

Comment: Rectangle is a simple rectangle representation, intentionally. It's simplicity is by design because that increases it's generality. You are unfortunately looking to the wrong type it implement the behavior you want (a rectangle  is too low level, you want a higher level abstraction).

Comment: @HaydenPerry, as Josh says, `Rectangle` isn't _meant_ to be complicated and full of things like collision detection. It's just meant to be... a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, most programs will separate geometry for rendering from geometry for physics. (This is because rendered models can be incredibly detailed, and hit testing against each polygon will take way longer than say, a couple quadtree intersection tests.)

If you're using a small number of simple rectangles, you could simply test each rectangle against every other rectangle that exists. This is O(n^2), though, so it will scale dramatically as the number of rectangles increases; when performance starts to suffer, you should look into more "organized" collision detection/physics processing schemes.